# Methods call count asp.net

Tags: asp.net, performance

in my ASP.NET application, I caught the culprit where a method which performs simple call to DB connection has been called many times (I set a breakpoint and it got hit couple times, unexpected), what is the suitable tool to use in this case to profile and calculate how many times a method is called and which method is calling it?

Comment: Any profiler. ANTS Profiler, dotTrace, take your pick.

Comment: I am using MiniProfiler, which I guess it doesn't do the job?

Answer (score 3):

You can use tools like ANTS profiler, as suggested above. If you just want to see who is calling your method, you can use Visual Studio's call hierarchy feature. You can find it in the `View` menu or by clicking Ctrl+Alt+K.

Here is a small tutorial on using it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/01/19/using-the-call-hierarchy-c-only-vstiptool0005.aspx

This has the advantage of being free and already there.

Comment: Any ways that I can trace how many times a method is called? Or the life cycle of how a page is rendered? I am aware of .NET page lifecycle and not referring to that.

Comment: You can see **where** the method is called and you can put break points near the relevant calls to see how they work and when they are called. It is also convenient to set the calling method as a root as well and the follow and see how and where it is called.